# Using AngularJS RouteParams with variable routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My `AngularJS` app has an `item list` view (which is basically a large list of items that the user can select from) and an `item detail` view. I have the routes currently set up like so:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/index',
        controller: indexCtrl
      }).
      when('/itemDetail/:id', { 
        templateUrl: 'partials/itemDetail',
        controller: itemDetailCtrl
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);


function itemDetailCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('/api/post/' + $routeParams.id).
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.post = data.post;
    });
}
```

For the `itemDetail/:id` route, I want the option of having more than one :id here (e.g. '/:id1+:id2+:id3'). The system should work if the user selects one item, two items or more items.

A possible solution that I haven't quite been able to get to work:

- When the user selects several items, my app logs the items' unique `id` in an array
- When going to the detail view, the route becomes `'itemDetail/STRING` where `STRING` is a string made from all the `id`s in the array, with a `+` between them. E.g.: `itemDetail/item1+item2+item3`
- In `itemDetailCtrl`, I take the string, split it at the `+` symbols and create a new array, as before
- I then use an `ng-repeat` to take those `ids` and load the details from my database into my view.

This was the first solution that came to mind, but it seems quite laborious and not particularly elegant. Is there a better way to achieve this, and if so, how do I update itemDetailCtrl to reflect the multiple ids?

Comment: You could try passing a "+" delimited list of ID's to :id and then just do:
    $scope.ids = $routeParams.id.split('+');

Answer (score 0):

Since the URLs aren't for a specific item and can have multiple I would go with a URL more like `itemDetail?item=item1&item=item2&item=item3` and then with `$routeParams` you should get `$routeParams.item = [item1, item2, item3]`